# connect ECONNREFUSED ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

```
var express = require('express'),
routes = require('./routes'),
http = require('http'),
path = require('path');

  var app = express();
  console.log(__dirname);
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views/')))

  app.get('/', routes.index);

  var mysql      = require('mysql');
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'test',
    password : 'pass000',
    database : 'testdb'
  });

  connection.connect();

  connection.query('SELECT * from users', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err)
      console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
    else
      console.log('Error while performing Query.' + err);
  });

  connection.end();

  http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){

    console.log('Express is running ...');

  });
```

I have error named "connect ECONNREFUSED".
Where is mistake in my code?? any ideas to correct this???

I searched this error but cant find answer :(
Im learning with thi [enter link description here](https://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

"ECONNREFUSED" is notifying you that there is already server running or port reserved. So please kill that instance first and try to run it again.

Comment: How can i do that? im very noob :(

Comment: ECONNREFUSED means a connection attempt was made to a nonexistent endpoint. Ensure MySql is running locally and the connection parameters in your node app are correct.

Comment: keithmo and what can i do?? my query not working againg  :(